# VSTi envelope implementation

Tags: c++, logic, vst, envelope

For a university assignment I have to write a simple VSTi additive synth. I have most of the work done, I just cannot get my ADSR envelope to do anything.

I think (and am definitely not sure) that the time variable, and/or the logic that decides the stage of the envelope is causing it not function as expected.

If the time variable for the envelope is incremented within the processReplacing() loop the code complies but crashes the host.

When incrementing time within each adsr multiplication, it compiles and runs in a host, just doesn't work as wanted.

I would have thought that incrementing time in the processReplacing() loop was the was to go, apparently not.

If anyone can see what is causing the envelope not to work and can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

I am really not sure what bits of code to attach so have done all of it.

Thanks,

VST_Plug_in.h

```
#ifndef __VST_Plug_in__
#define __VST_Plug_in__

#include "audioeffectx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "ADSR.h"
#include "timer.h"

const int NUMBER_OF_INPUTS = 0;
const int NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS = 2;
const int NUMBER_OF_PROGRAMS = 0;
const int NUMBER_OF_PARAMETERS = 5;

enum
    {
    kGain,
    kAttack,
    kDecay,
    kSustain,
    kRelease
    };

// Base frequency (A4- 440Hz) for use in generating frequency table
    const float BASE_A4  = 440.0;
    const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

class VST_Plug_in : public AudioEffectX
{
public:
    VST_Plug_in (audioMasterCallback audioMaster);
    ~VST_Plug_in ();

    virtual void processReplacing (float** inputs, float** outputs, VstInt32 sampleFrames);
    virtual VstInt32 processEvents (VstEvents* events);
    virtual VstInt32 canDo (char* text);

    // MIDI data : holds data about current state of MIDI (note on/off, frequency, velocity)
    int keyDown;
    int* pkeyDown;

    long currentNote; // the MIDI note number of the last note on (key down)
    float currentVelocity; // current MIDI note velocity (0 -> 1)
    float *m_pfFrequencyTable; // will store a list of frequency values (for note->frequency conversion)

    double partial1, partial2, partial3, partial4, partial5, partial6, partial7, partial8, leftSample, rightSample;
    float maxAttack, minAttack, attack, maxDecay, minDecay, decay, minRelease, maxRelease, release, sustain, frequency, sampleRate, gain;
    long partialTime;

    void noteOff ();
    void noteOn (long liNote, long liVelocity);
    float getAttack(float value);
    float sendAttack();
    float getDecay(float value);
    float sendDecay();
    float getSustain(float value);
    float sendSustain();
    float getRelease(float value);
    float sendRelease();

    virtual void setParameter (VstInt32 index, float value);
    virtual float getParameter (VstInt32 index);
    virtual void getParameterLabel (VstInt32 index, char* label);
    virtual void getParameterDisplay (VstInt32 index, char* text);
    virtual void getParameterName (VstInt32 index, char* text); 

    ADSR env;
    timer universalTime;
    long* pTime;
};

#endif
```

VST_Plug_in.cpp

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// VST Plug-Ins SDK
// Version 2.4      $Date: 2005/11/15 15:14:03 $
// 
// Category     : VST 2.x SDK Samples
// Filename     : VST_Plug_in.cpp
// Created by   : Steinberg Media Technologies
// Description  : a crap additive synth
//
// © 2005, Steinberg Media Technologies, All Rights Reserved
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include "VST_Plug_in.h"
#include "audioeffectx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "ADSR.h"
#include "timer.h"

AudioEffect* createEffectInstance (audioMasterCallback audioMaster)
{
    return new VST_Plug_in (audioMaster);
}

VST_Plug_in::VST_Plug_in (audioMasterCallback audioMaster)
: AudioEffectX (audioMaster, NUMBER_OF_PROGRAMS, NUMBER_OF_PARAMETERS)  
{
    setNumInputs (NUMBER_OF_INPUTS);        // stereo in
    setNumOutputs (NUMBER_OF_OUTPUTS);      // stereo out
    setUniqueID ('Add1');   // identify
    canProcessReplacing (); // supports replacing output
    isSynth (); // Informs host that this is a VSTi
    sampleRate = getSampleRate();//get sample rate from host

    leftSample  = 0.0;
    rightSample = 0.0;
    frequency = 0.0;
    gain = 1.f;
    currentVelocity = 0.f;
    currentNote = 0;
    keyDown = 2;
    pkeyDown = &keyDown;
    partialTime = 0;
    partial1 = partial2 = partial3 = partial4 = partial5 = partial6 = partial7 = partial8 = 0.0;
    maxAttack = 384000;
    minAttack = 1;
    attack = 44100;
    maxDecay = 192000;
    minDecay = 1;
    decay = 22050;
    maxRelease = 768000;
    minRelease = 1;
    release = 96000;
    sustain = 1.f;

    ADSR env;
    timer universalTime;
    pTime = universalTime.timeCount();

    // initialise frequency table
    m_pfFrequencyTable = new float [128] ; // 128 Midi notes
    if (m_pfFrequencyTable)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<  128; i++)
        {
            m_pfFrequencyTable[i] = BASE_A4 *powf(2.f,(i-57)/12.f) ;
        }
    }   
}

VST_Plug_in::~VST_Plug_in ()
{
    // nothing to do here
}

// this is where the intresting stuff happens :0
void VST_Plug_in::processReplacing (float** inputs, float** outputs, VstInt32 sampleFrames)
{
    float* out1 = outputs[0];
    float* out2 = outputs[1];

    for(int i = 0; i < sampleFrames; i++)
    {
        // NEW : only send out audio if there is a note on currently
        frequency = m_pfFrequencyTable[currentNote];

        partial1 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*partialTime++*(frequency/sampleRate))* 0.125;//Nyquist frequency issues.  
        partial2 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*partialTime*((2*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;//Obvious looping/foldback of frequencies with higher notes.
        partial3 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*partialTime*((3*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;//Appears mostly fixed when time is only 
        partial4 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*partialTime*((4*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;//incremented with the fundamental.
        partial5 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*partialTime*((5*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;
        partial6 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*partialTime*((6*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;
        partial7 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*partialTime*((7*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125;
        partial8 = (double)sin(2.0*PI*partialTime*((8*frequency)/sampleRate))* 0.125; 
        leftSample = partial1 + partial2 + partial3 + partial4 + partial5 + partial6 + partial7 + partial8;

        leftSample = (env.process(leftSample, attack, decay, sustain, release, pkeyDown, pTime) * currentVelocity); //needs to be pointer as data is duplicated when sent.
        //(*pTime)++; //crashes host if uncommented
        leftSample = leftSample * gain;
        rightSample = leftSample;

        // write samples to output buffer 
        (*out1++) = leftSample;
        (*out2++) = rightSample;
    }
}

// NEW : overriden function, tells host what the plugin can do (see notes)
VstInt32 VST_Plug_in::canDo(char *text)
{
    if (!strcmp (text, "receiveVstEvents"))     // SimpleSynth can receive VST events
        return 1;
    if (!strcmp (text, "receiveVstMidiEvent"))  // SimpleSynth can receive VST MIDI events
        return 1;
    return -1;  // explicitly can't do; 0 => don't know 
}

// NEW : this process function is called to collect incoming VST events
VstInt32 VST_Plug_in::processEvents (VstEvents* events)
{
    // parse event list
    for (long i = 0; i < events->numEvents; i++)
    {
        if ((events->events[i])->type == kVstMidiType)
        {
            VstMidiEvent* event = (VstMidiEvent*)events->events[i];
            char* midiData = event->midiData;
            long status = midiData[0] & 0xf0;       // ignoring channel

            if (status == 0x90 || status == 0x80)   // we only look at notes
            {
                long note = midiData[1];
                long velocity = midiData[2];

                if (status == 0x80)
                {
                    velocity = 0;   
                    // set velocity to zero if it is a note off message
                }
                if (!velocity && (note == currentNote))
                {
                    noteOff ();
                }
                else
                {
                    noteOn (note, velocity);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1; // indicate that we wish to receive more events
}

void VST_Plug_in::noteOn(long liNote, long liVelocity)
{
    keyDown = 1;
    partialTime = 0;
    currentNote = liNote;
    currentVelocity = liVelocity / 127.f;
}

void VST_Plug_in::noteOff()
{
    keyDown = 2;
    currentVelocity = 0;
}

// this function is called whenever the fader is moved
void VST_Plug_in::setParameter (VstInt32 index, float value)
{
    switch (index)
    {
        case kGain : gain = value;break;  
        case kAttack : attack = getAttack(value); break; //need vale in samples for envelope here
        case kDecay : decay = getDecay(value); break;
        case kSustain : sustain = getSustain(value); break;
        case kRelease : release = getRelease(value); break;
    }
}

// this function is called whenever the gui requires data
float VST_Plug_in::getParameter (VstInt32 index)

{
    switch (index)
    {
        case kGain : return gain;break;
        case kAttack : return sendAttack(); break; //need 0 - 1 val here
        case kDecay : return sendDecay();break;
        case kSustain : return sendSustain();break;
        case kRelease : return sendRelease();break;
    }
}

// getParameterName places the parameter name on the plug in
void VST_Plug_in::getParameterName (VstInt32 index, char* label)

{
    switch (index)
    {
        case kGain : vst_strncpy (label, "Gain", kVstMaxParamStrLen);break;
        case kAttack : vst_strncpy (label, "Attack", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kDecay : vst_strncpy (label, "Decay", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kSustain : vst_strncpy (label, "Sustain", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kRelease : vst_strncpy (label, "Release", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
    }
}

// getParameterDisplay displays the parameter value on the plug-in
void VST_Plug_in::getParameterDisplay (VstInt32 index, char* text)

{
    switch (index)
    {
        case kGain : dB2string(gain, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen);break;
        case kAttack : float2string(attack, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kDecay : float2string(decay, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kSustain: dB2string(sustain, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kRelease : float2string(release, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
    }
    /*linear display
    float2string(gain, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen);
    dB display
    dB2string (gain, text, kVstMaxParamStrLen);*/
}

void VST_Plug_in::getParameterLabel (VstInt32 index, char* label)

{
    switch (index)
    {
        case kGain : vst_strncpy (label, "dB", kVstMaxParamStrLen);break;
        case kAttack : vst_strncpy (label, "Samples", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kDecay : vst_strncpy (label, "Samples", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kSustain : vst_strncpy (label, "dB", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
        case kRelease : vst_strncpy (label, "Samples", kVstMaxParamStrLen); break;
    }
}

float VST_Plug_in::getAttack(float value)
{   
    attack = minAttack + ((maxAttack-minAttack) * value);
    return attack;
}
float VST_Plug_in::sendAttack()
{   
    float retAttVal;
    retAttVal = (attack - minAttack) / (maxAttack-minAttack);
    return retAttVal;
}

float VST_Plug_in::getDecay(float value)
{
    decay = minDecay + ((maxDecay-minDecay) * value);
    return decay;
}
float VST_Plug_in::sendDecay()
{
    float retDecVal;
    retDecVal = (decay - minDecay) / (maxDecay-minDecay);
    return retDecVal;
}

float VST_Plug_in::getSustain(float value)
{
    sustain = value;
    return sustain;
}
float VST_Plug_in::sendSustain()
{
    return sustain;
}

float VST_Plug_in::getRelease(float value)
{
    release = minRelease + ((maxRelease-minRelease) * value);
    return release;
}
float VST_Plug_in::sendRelease()
{
    float retRelVal;
    retRelVal = (release - minRelease) / (maxRelease-minRelease);
    return retRelVal;
}
```

ADSR.h

```
#ifndef __ADSR 
#define __ADSR

#include <math.h>

class ADSR
{
public:
    ADSR();
    ~ADSR();

    long susTimer; 
    int stage;
    double process(double currentSamp, float attack, float decay, float sustain, float release, int* pKeyState, long* pTime); 
};
#endif
```

ADSR.cpp

```
#include <math.h>
#include "ADSR.h"


ADSR::ADSR()
{
    stage = 1;
    susTimer = 0;
}
ADSR::~ADSR()
{
}

double ADSR::process(double currentSamp, float attack, float decay, float sustain, float release, int* pKeyState, long* pTime)
{
    if(stage == 1 && *pTime >= (attack + decay + susTimer + release))
    {
        *pTime = 0;
    }

    while(*pTime < attack)
    {
        currentSamp = currentSamp * ((1.0f / attack) + 1.0f);
        (*pTime)++;//doesn't crash but doesnt do anything either
        stage = 1;
        return currentSamp;
    }

    while(*pTime < (attack + decay))
    {
        currentSamp = currentSamp * (sustain / decay);
        (*pTime)++;//doesn't crash but doesnt do anything either
        stage = 2;
        return currentSamp;
    }

    while(*pTime > (attack + decay))
    {
        currentSamp = currentSamp * 1.0f;
        susTimer++;
        stage = 3;
        return currentSamp;
    }

    while(*pTime < (attack + decay + susTimer + release) && *pKeyState == 2)
    {
        currentSamp = currentSamp * (sustain / release);
        (*pTime)++;//doesn't crash but doesnt do anything either
        stage = 4;
        return currentSamp;
    }
}
```

timer.h

```
#ifndef __timer
#define __timer

#include <math.h>


class timer
{
public:
    timer();
    ~timer();

    long time;
    long* pTime;

    long* timeCount();
};
#endif
```

timer.cpp

```
#include <math.h>
#include "timer.h"


timer::timer()
{
    time = 0;
    pTime = &time;
}
timer::~timer()
{
}

long* timer::timeCount()
{
    return pTime;
}
```

Comment: have you stepped through your envelope code in a debugger?

Comment: That really a bit too much code for anyone to enjoy searching the mistake. At least tell us what you mean by "doesn't work as wanted".

Comment: Why are you using `while` loops that always `return` in the first iteration? Those are equivalent to simple `if`. Probably related to your problem.

Comment: Admittedly a lot of code, so thank you for looking. Can you explain how the while loop would be causing issue as opposed to if statements? Not working as expected = the envelope is not applying the level ramp over time as expected. I have however made a little progress. Am now struggling with the level multiplier, levels are staying constant as it moves through the envelope, not ramping. I have tried storing a previous sample and mixing with the current like with filters, but that doesn't work either. At least all stages up to Release are now captured and move on accordingly.

Comment: The mixing of prevSamp and currentSamp causes signal overload whilst in the relevant segment of ADSR. when it moves on to sustain it holds the level set by sustain.